# Flickity stops working the moment i use *NgFor

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, flickity

I am trying to use Flickity in an angular app that i am building. Here is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sjtzqn?file=src/app/app.component.html) I am also aware of the ngx-flickity but i do not want this as it isn't production ready.

This code below works

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-cell">...</div>
    <div class="carousel-cell">...</div>
    <div class="carousel-cell">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

The moment i use *NgFor, it stops working without any errors

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-cell" *ngFor="let product of products">
        {{ product.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

I also tried the prepend method but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are suing `document.querySelector('.carousel')` which will return only one element (the first one) in case you have multiple carousels elements it won't work for the others.
Second, you want to instantiate the `flick` once you have the data returned and once they are rendered.
A quick fix is to use this:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
      this.products = products;
      setTimeout( () => {
       document.querySelectorAll(".carousel").forEach(c => {
        let flick = new flickity(c, { cellAlign: "left", contain: true});
        })});
    });
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

a better solution than using `setTimeout` is to use the `ChangeDetecrotRef` to force change detection explicitly (rendering) right after receiving the data from the server.

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
...
  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
      this.products = products;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
      document.querySelectorAll(".carousel").forEach(c => {
        let flick = new flickity(c, { cellAlign: "left", contain: true});
        });
    });
  }
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-54v524?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Without using setTimeout, how can i do it? Cheers

Comment: I agree that setTimeout is not the most sophisticated way to do it, I don't have a ready answer now.. I'll update the answer if I find something

Comment: you can use  `ChangeDetectorRef` instead

Comment: Cheers. The chageDetectionRef works nicely

Answer (score 0):

it seems you should initialize flickity after you get the data and you have template initialized. in your stackblits moving `this.flick = ...` code to `ngAfterViewInit()` hook fixes the problem

Comment: that won't work in case you update the service to simpulate network latency `return  of(this.products).pipe(delay(1000));`